# Why does my BSDF black material rendering light grey in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color

Is there some tweaking to do to have a BSDF shader black material render correctly?
All image materials that contain black parts come out OK, but the simplest hard color material with an Hex: 000000 value, is rendered light grey under cycles.
Here are two screen shots, one in material preview [image: one in material preview], there the color is near black. The other in rendered preview [image: The other in rendered preview], the selected element that appears light grey should actually be black.

Comment: Try playing with the material settings a bit. Increase roughness to lower the amount of reflected light off of the material. Decrease specular reflections

Comment: Thanks Jiří, I had already augmented the roughness with very little impact. I wasn't aware of what the specular settings were for, but that was the needed tweak.
Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing:) I highly recommend to watch this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQ0qtcSymDI&t=1361s In 28 minutes all shader nodes are expleined including all their options and desription of what they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your specular! I recreated the material and this is what I can see:

[image]
[image]

This is when keeping the same exact material however if you lower the specular to something like 0.15 you get a much deeper black while reserving the roughness of the object:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Zarbio,
I knew it would be something basic like that. I fiddled around with many of them but not knowing what I was actually doing (most of those settings are a puzzle to me), I must have missed that one.
Problem solved, and solution duly noted.